# Async method does not recognize yield return method?

Tags: c#, yield

**PROBLEM**

When i try to call my "normal" method in async method , then it gets ignored from Debugger[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfpVK.png).

Here is my async method

```
 internal async static Task<DefinitionsModel> DeserializeAsync(this string path)
 {
        var model = new DefinitionsModel();
        var content = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(path);

        model.Pages = content.GetPages();

        return model;
 }
```

and here is my "normal" method

```
private static IEnumerable<PageModel> GetPages(this string content)
{            
        var level = 0;
        var value = nameof(PageModel.Page).GetDElement<PageModel>();
        var start_with_line = $"{level} {value} ";
        var end_with_line = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(Environment.NewLine, 2));

        var expression = $@"\b{start_with_line}\S * {end_with_line}\b";
        var matches = content.GetPagesFromContent(expression);


        yield return new PageModel();
}
```

**HELPER PICTURES**

[image: image link]

Comment: Thats probably because your `IEnumerable<T>` result isn't iterated/persisted. For example your method is executed when it is used in a foreach loop.

Comment: @phuzi my question is not about List vs IEnumeable....

Comment: It's really odd to have a method with a single `yield` statement, why not just return a single `PageModel`?

Comment: I agree the title is misleading, but the explanation there is actually quite useful. @OverZer0

Comment: @DavidG i wasnt done with my methods, i just want to see what values has the "mathes collection"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`yield` doesn't yield unless it's enumerated. In this case:

```
model.Pages = content.GetPages();
```

There is no enumeration. You could however do this:

```
model.Pages = content.GetPages().ToList();
```

You consume an iterator method by using a `foreach` statement or LINQ query, and unsurprisingly `ToList()` iterates the `IEnumerable` using a `foreach`.

Though in all honesty, I am struggling to work out what you are doing, most likely need to rethink `GetPages` altogether.

[yield (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield)

> When you use the `yield` contextual keyword in a statement, you indicate
> that the method, operator, or get accessor in which it appears is an
> *iterator*. Using `yield` to define an iterator removes the need for an
> explicit extra class (the class that holds the state for an
> enumeration, see IEnumerator for an example) when you implement the
> IEnumerable and IEnumerator pattern for a custom collection type.
>
> **You use a yield return statement to return each element one at a time.**
>
> You consume an iterator method by using a foreach statement or LINQ
> query. Each iteration of the foreach loop calls the iterator method.
> When a yield return statement is reached in the iterator method,
> expression is returned, and the current location in code is retained.
> Execution is restarted from that location the next time that the
> iterator function is called.

Answer (score 1):

Your `GetPages` method returns an `IEnumerable<T>` with `yield return`. The compiler builds a state machine from that code.

That code will only get executed once the enumerator obtained using the `GetEnumerator()` method from the generated state machine will be called and iterated.